# How to listen click action of the button which is from Activity on fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, listener

i have an activity that has a Fragment.I want to listen my button which in my activity from my fragment. Sample Code is here;

MainActivity

```
  OnSearchClickListener searchListener;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
......
}


myButton.setOnclickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            searchListener.OnSearchClick();
        }
    });
```

myFragment

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements OnSearchClickListener{
........
 @Override
public void OnSearchClick() {

   Toast.makeText(context,"This message from fragment",......
}
```

Listener

```
public interface OnSearchClickListener {
public void OnSearchClick();
```

}

i used this structure. but it gave me nullpointerexception. Do you tell me how can i listen a button which in an Activity from a fragment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you tell me how can i listen a button which in an Activity from a
>   fragment ?

Doing in right way but forget to initialize `searchListener` object using Fragment object which currently adding in FragmentManager. do it as:

```
MyFragment  mFragment = new MyFragment();
...
ft.add(R.id.content, mFragment).commit();
searchListener=(OnSearchClickListener)mFragment;
```

Now use `searchListener` object for calling `OnSearchClick` from Activity on Button click.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to initialize `OnSearchClickListener searchListener;` inside your onCreate method from the MainActivity.

You should have something like this in you onCreate:

```
MyFragment frag = new MyFragment();
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.main_activity_container, frag);
            ft.commit();
```

before beginning the transaction, you do this:

```
searchListener = (OnSearchClickListener) frag;
```